# Remove all attributes not in whitelist from all HTML tags

Tags: php, html, attributes, domdocument, sanitization

So, far I can only keep one attribute but I am trying to keep both class and id attributes left in the HTML tags

Code:

```
$string = '<div id="one-id" class="someClassName">Some text <a href="#" title="Words" id="linkId" class="classLink">link</a> with only the class and id  attrtibutes.</div>';

preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:[^>]*(\sclass=['\"][^'\"]*['\"]))?[^>]*?(\/?)>/i", '<$1$2$3>', $string);
```

Output:

```
<div class="someClassName">Some text <a class="classLink">link</a> with only the class and id  attrtibutes./div>
```

I am trying to remove all other attributes from every tag except the class and id attributes.

Using the DOMDocument(); adds extra p tags to the output for some reason and I believe xpath is faster?

Comment: The first think people always warn about is to [not use regular expressions when working with HTML](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/regex-when-to-avoid). That is sound advice. You would normally use something like [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php) (there are serveral alternatives).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all nodes in the dom, then loop over all attributes in reverse so that you can safely prune attributes that are not in your whitelist.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8VdRc))

```
$html = '<div id="one-id" class="someClassName">Some text <a href="#" title="Words" id="linkId" class="classLink">link</a> with only the class and id  attrtibutes.</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//*') as $node) {
    for ($i = $node->attributes->length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $attr = $node->attributes->item($i);
        if (!in_array($attr->name, ['id', 'class'])) {
            $node->removeAttribute($attr->name);
        }
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div id="one-id" class="someClassName">Some text <a id="linkId" class="classLink">link</a> with only the class and id  attrtibutes.</div>
```

---

...actually, XPath isn't really needed because we are iterating every node in the dom. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5o7lb))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) {
    for ($i = $node->attributes->length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $attr = $node->attributes->item($i);
        if (!in_array($attr->name, ['id', 'class'])) {
            $node->removeAttribute($attr->name);
        }
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

---

Trying to parse valid HTML with a regular expression is going to be one or more of the following:

1. Inaccurate/Unreliable,
2. Convoluted/Verbose,
3. Hard to read,
4. Hard to maintain

Regex does not know the difference between tags and text that merely looks like tags.  What if the HTML tags and attributes use upper and lower case? What if single quotes, double quotes and/or backticks are used? What if an attribute has no assignment (e.g. `readonly` or `checked`)? What if a `data-` attribute name ends with `id` or `title`? What if an attribute value contains a quoting symbol which is escaped instead of html encoded? What if text looks like a starting tag, but isn't a tag at all?

These are valid reasons to steer clear of parsing valid HTML with regex.

Comment: DOM is definitely the way to go.